# Tkinter Moving Graph created through GUI - not from the start

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, animation

Why isn't this graph moving? Or even being created? I've gotten graphs to move in tkinter before, but they would always open up immediately as the GUI opens, but I need the user to be able to choose their own dataset from a file within the GUI.

Thus, I have a function that chooses a file and creates the lists which matplotlib uses, but if I create the

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import time
import math
import serial


from numpy import arrange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot at plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

global x
global y

def open_file():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(mode = 'r', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv'), ('Text Files', '*.txt'), ('All Files', '*.*')])
    if file != None:
        unprocessed_content = file.read()
        unprocessed_content = unprocessed_content.split('\n')
        unprocessed_content.remove('')

        for line in unprocessed_content:
            x.append(float(line.split(',')[0]))
            y.append(float(line.split(',')[1]))

tkTop = tkinter.Tk()

fileOpener = tkinter.Button(tkTop, text = "Open File", command = open_file, height = 4, fg = 'black', bg = 'red', width = 8, bd = 5)
fileOpener.pack()

try:
    x #just to pass over this section and not start the graph if the user hasn't chosen a file yet
    fig = plt.Figure()

    x_current = x[:10]  #I want to only show part of the window at a time, so I thought I would do it in segments of 10 arbitrarily

    def animate(i):
        line.set_ydata(y[i:i+10])
        return line,

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = tkTop)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y[:10])
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1,200), interval = 25, blit = False)    

except NameError:
    pass

tkTop.mainloop()
```

I think that's all the relevant code for my problem... so basically what happens is that I open up the GUI, and there's no graph (which is what I want) but then I click on the button to open a file and still nothing happens with the graph?

I kind of assumed that tkTop.mainloop() would run continuously again and again, so that it would continue to update the animation? Is that not right?

Comment: you should put code in function and run function when you need it - ie. when you click button.

Comment: your the biggest mistake is `except NameError: pass` - you may have error in code but you can't see it. You should at least do `except NameError as ex: print(ex)` and maybe it could explain problem.

Comment: all variables created outside functions are `global` - so using `global x` is useless. We use `global` inside function to inform function that it has to use global/external variable instead of create local variable. Eventually you should create global variable with some default value at start - ie. `x = []`

Answer (score 0):

You may have problem for two reasons:

---

**First**

You do the worst thing - you use `pass` in `except`.

```
except NameError:
    pass
```

This way you don't see that you have other mistake which makes all problem.

You should at least display error

```
except NameError as ex:
    print('ex:', ex)
```

and you would know what makes all problem.

---

**Second:**

`global` is not for creating global variables. All variables created outside functions/classes are globla. And `global` is used inside function to inform function that it has to use external/global variable instead of local variable.

Problem is that your graph raise error because `x`,`y` don't exist. And you should create them by assigning default value

```
x = []
y = []
```

And now it should show graph

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code.

At start it displays empty plot and run animation (but it has nothing to display).

I added button to generate some fake data - so everyone can test it.

I didn't make one thing: restart animation after loading/generating new data and start at first frame `i` - so now it uses new `y` but old `x` (using old `i` in `animate`).

Frankly, it could be good to create animation only when data are loaded/generate, and replace previous animation.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import csv

import random

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

def open_file():
    global x
    global y

    file = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv'),
                                             ('Text Files', '*.txt'),
                                             ('All Files', '*.*')])

    if file:
        print('read file')

        x = []
        y = []
        
        reader_csv = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader_csv:
            x.append(float(row[0]))
            y.append(float(row[1]))

        if x:
            ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
        if y:
            ax.set_ylim(min(y), max(y))
        
def generate_data():
    global x
    global y
    
    print('generate data')
    
    # fake values
    x = list(range(250))
    y = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(250)]

    # 
    if x:
        ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    if y:
        ax.set_ylim(min(y), max(y))

def animate(i):
    print('i:', i, x[i:i+10], y[i:i+10])
    
    current_x = x[i:i+10]
    current_y = y[i:i+10]
    
    line.set_xdata(current_x)
    line.set_ydata(current_y)

    if current_x:    
        ax.set_xlim(min(current_x), max(current_x))

    #canvas.draw()
    
    return line,

# --- main ---

# default values at start
x = []
y = []

# - GUI -

tk_top = tk.Tk()

file_opener = tk.Button(tk_top, text="Open File", command=open_file)
file_opener.pack()

data_generator = tk.Button(tk_top, text="Generate Data", command=generate_data)
data_generator.pack()

# - empty plot -

try:
    fig = plt.Figure()

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=tk_top)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = ax.plot([], [])
    
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 250, interval=250, blit=False)    

except NameError as ex:
    print(ex)

print('mainloop')
tk_top.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Version which doesn't create animation at start (when there is no data) but it create animation after loading/generating data.

I also used this to create buttons `STOP`, `START`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import csv

import random

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

def open_file():
    global x
    global y

    file = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv'),
                                             ('Text Files', '*.txt'),
                                             ('All Files', '*.*')])

    if file:
        print('read file')

        x = []
        y = []
        
        reader_csv = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader_csv:
            x.append(float(row[0]))
            y.append(float(row[1]))

        if x:
            ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
        if y:
            ax.set_ylim(min(y), max(y))
            
        # stop previous animation
        if ani:
            ani._stop()
        #del ani

        # create new animation    
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 250, interval=250, blit=False)    
        ani._start()
        
def generate_data():
    global x
    global y
    global ani
    
    print('generate data')
    
    # fake values
    x = list(range(250))
    y = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(250)]

    # 
    if x:
        ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    if y:
        ax.set_ylim(min(y), max(y))

    # stop previous animation
    if ani:
        ani._stop()
    #del ani

    # create new animation    
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 250, interval=250, blit=False)    
    ani._start()
    
def animate(i):
    print('i:', i, x[i:i+10], y[i:i+10])
    
    current_x = x[i:i+10]
    current_y = y[i:i+10]
    
    line.set_xdata(current_x)
    line.set_ydata(current_y)

    if current_x:    
        ax.set_xlim(min(current_x), max(current_x))

    #canvas.draw()
    
    return line,

def stop_animation():
    if ani:
        # matplotlib 3.4.0+   # https://matplotlib.org/3.4.0/gallery/animation/pause_resume.html
        #ani.pause() 
        # older matplotlib 
        ani.event_source.stop()
        if ani._blit:
            for artist in ani._drawn_artists:
                artist.set_animated(False)

def start_animation():
    if ani:
        # matplotlib 3.4.0+   # https://matplotlib.org/3.4.0/gallery/animation/pause_resume.html
        #ani.resume() 
        # older matplotlib 
        ani.event_source.start()
        if ani._blit:
            for artist in ani._drawn_artists:
                artist.set_animated(True)        
            
# --- main ---

# default values at start
x = []
y = []
ani = None

# - GUI -

tk_top = tk.Tk()

file_opener = tk.Button(tk_top, text="Open File", command=open_file)
file_opener.pack()

data_generator = tk.Button(tk_top, text="Generate Data", command=generate_data)
data_generator.pack()

# - empty plot -

try:
    fig = plt.Figure()

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=tk_top)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = ax.plot([], [])
    
    # don't create animation at start
    #ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 250, interval=250, blit=False)    
    #ani.pause()  # it needs newer matplotlib
    
except NameError as ex:
    print(ex)
    
stop = tk.Button(tk_top, text="Stop", command=stop_animation)
stop.pack()

start = tk.Button(tk_top, text="Start", command=start_animation)
start.pack()

print('mainloop')
tk_top.mainloop()
```